# How to add a polygon around a polyline leaflet

Tags: json, leaflet, polyline, turfjs

Hi guys i am quite new to leaflet and turfjs and need a little bit of help.

I have made a polyline which works but what i want is a polygon/buffer that follows the polyline and users can change the width of the polygon/buffer in nm's by slider or text field.

If anyone knows this would be a great help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can utilize [this](https://github.com/Eclipse1979/leaflet-slider) slider plugin.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RypEOM

```
var polygon = turf.polygon([[[-81, 41], [-88, 36], [-84, 31], [-80, 33], [-77, 39], [-81, 41]]]);   
turfLayer.addData(polygon);

L.control.slider(function(value) {
    if (turfLayer.getLayers().length > 1) {
        turfLayer.removeLayer(turfLayer.getLayers()[1]);
    }
    var buffered = turf.buffer(polygon, value, {units: 'kilometers'});
    turfLayer.addData(buffered);

}, {
    max: 100,
        value: 0,
    step: 10,
    size: '250px',
        orientation:'vertical',
    id: 'slider'
}).addTo(map);
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply when following this example in my code it says there is an error with var slider, it says its defined but never used?

Comment: It must be just a warning, but of course the variable is not used anywhere so you can delete it. I've updated the code accordingly.

Comment: I have got the slider to show on screen and it works, my problem is now the coords are wrong as they are set as in the demo. I need it to be the same as my polyline which goes to around 15 L.LatLng if that makes sense. If i type in all the coords it dispears from screen or is in the wrong position